# Styling a GridView cellpadding OnEditing mode

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, Asp.Net with C#

You know when you see your GridView all fine but when you click on EDIT it expands itself and it cross the lines of the div on the page ? That's what is happening to me.

I'd like to know HOW do I edit a CellPadding and CellSpacing While it's on Editing mode ?

Thank you !

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of what is happening or the aspx file  of your page.. I cannot fully understand your problem.Is your datagridview nested inside a div?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the cell padding and spacing won't help solve your problem.

The reason the gridview expands outside of the div is because it generates lengthy input controls(textbox, datetime pickers etc) when a row is in edit mode.

### I can think of two solutions:

1) Change the width of the gridview edit row input controls:

```
<style type="text/css">
.editRow input
{
    width:60px;
}
</style>
```

**Add the style to your gridview:**

```
<asp:GridView EditRowStyle-CssClass="editRow"...
```

2) Place your gridview inside a div and set the div's `overflow` css property to auto.Which will generate scroll bars when your gridview is in edit mode.

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .gridParent
        {
            width: 700px;
            height:300px;
            overflow: auto;
        }
    </style>

<div class="gridParent">
    <!--Your grid view-->
    </div>
```